# How do I increase windows service startup timeout

Tags: windows, windows-service

I have migrated software to a very slow sever. Some software services refuses to startup because of system timeout. How do I increase timeout from default 30 sec.(?) to several minutes?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 78):

[You can modify the timeout value in the registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/922918).

---

```
1. Click Start, click Run, type regedit, and then click OK.
2. Locate and then click the following registry subkey:
 - HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
3. In the right pane, locate the ServicesPipeTimeout entry.

**Note**: If the ServicesPipeTimeout entry does not exist, you must create it. To do this, follow these steps:

 - On the Edit menu, point to New, and then click DWORD Value.
 - Type ServicesPipeTimeout, and then press ENTER. 
4. Right-click ServicesPipeTimeout, and then click Modify.
5. Click Decimal, type 60000, and then click OK.
 - This value represents the time in milliseconds before a service times out.
6. Restart the computer.
```

---

Comment: user149591 please mark this as the answer.

Comment: @NickDeMayo Seeing as how he hasn't been back since August 19th, that seems unlikely to happen.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Can't mods mark stuff as answered on behalf of the users? :)

Comment: For more discussion on how to control this timeout in other situations (Windows restart, etc) see this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29928342/434413

Comment: Does anybody know the maximum value for this registry entry? I've just tried putting 10 minutes (on Windows 10) and I have the impression my service already stops at 5 minutes.

Comment: @Dominique 2 to the 32nd power, minus 1.  Not that a value that high will do you any good.  That’s just how long Windows will wait... if a process is taking that long to start, it sounds to me like it’s having trouble starting, and it might not be the Windows service timeout that’s causing your pain.

Comment: I'm finding this works for `net stop` just fine as my batch files wait very long for big services to stop (MySQL8) but `net start` still times out and fails in my batch files soon after attempting to start.  Are there separate values for start/stop timeout?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a quick one-liner, which can be executed from an *elevated* PowerShell prompt, that sets the pending service timeout to 3 minutes:

`Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control" -Name ServicesPipeTimeout -Value 180000 -Type DWord`

Comment: Brilliant! Can't stand sludging through regedit.

Answer (score 1):

Please find a visualized answer by [appuals.com](https://appuals.com/how-to-fix-error-1053-the-service-did-not-respond-to-the-start-or-control-request-in-a-timely-fashion/)

[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Thanks for your answer, but please follow the [guidelines](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer). So: please answer with text and not just a picture (so it's easier to find and read), and add context to the link.